# html5 canvas save background

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am working with a canvas... I modified one to choose a background and when is finished the drawing save it with the background... until in the background choosing is all ok... now I have some issues that to be completely honest I don't know how to do

Here is the url where I am working: [canvas](http://www.grupovg.info/canvas/index.html)

The first problem is with the cursor... I need the canvas is displayed inside of tabs, when I draw the cursor instead of showing 0,0 within the canvas, is at 0,0 on page so when I start drawing the line is displayed like the next image:

[image: error in cursor]

The second issue is when I try to save the result...when is only draw lines the canvas is successfully saved but when is with the background not... You can try with the link I added above.

The last issue is when I click the eraser or the undo...the background and all I draw is deleted... I need only the last lines will erase, not all... can this be fixed?

Here I add the js: [canvas js](https://jsfiddle.net/ak2etLro/)

And here the grabado.php:

```
<?php
/**
* -------------------------------
* Customizable Settings
* -------------------------------
*/
$dd_savePath=str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__))."/tmp";
$prependSig="diag_";
/**
* -------------------------------
* End of customizable settings
* -------------------------------
*/
/**
* Attempt to create the needed save dir if not exist
*/
if(!is_dir($dd_savePath)) {
    @mkdir($dd_savePath,0777);
    @chmod($dd_savePath,0777);
}
//
$action=strip_tags(trim($_POST['action']));
$fileName=strip_tags(trim($_POST['file_name']));
$width=strip_tags(trim($_POST['width']));
$height=strip_tags(trim($_POST['height']));
$download=(isset($_POST['download']) ? strip_tags(trim($_POST['download'])) : strip_tags(trim($_GET['download'])));
/**
* @desc 
*/
class createSignature {
    private $img, $file, $dest;

    public function __construct($i,$d) {
        $this->file=$i;
        $this->dest=$d;
    }

    public function makePNG($w,$h) {
        $this->img=@imagecreatefrompng($this->file);
        //
        imagealphablending($this->img, true);   // setting alpha blending on
        imagesavealpha($this->img, true);       // save alphablending setting (important)
        //
        $canvas=self::makeCanvas('png',$w,$h);
        // Let's get our dims for original image
        $trueSize=getimagesize($this->file);
        //
        imagecopyresampled($canvas,$this->img,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$trueSize[0],$trueSize[1]);
        //
        if(imagepng($canvas,$this->dest)) {
            @chmod($this->dest,0777);
            @imagedestroy($this->img);
            @imagedestroy($canvas);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function makeCanvas($t,$w,$h) {
        switch($t) {
            case "png":
                $canvas=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
                imagecolortransparent($canvas, imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127));
                imagealphablending($canvas, false); // setting alpha blending on
                imagesavealpha($canvas, true);      // save alphablending setting (important)
                break;
            default:
        }
        //
        return $canvas;
    }
}
/**
* If download flag, then we're downloading a created signature image
*/
if($download!="") {
    //
    $downloadFile="{$dd_savePath}/{$download}";
    //
    $ctype="application/force-download";
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($downloadFile));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($downloadFile)."\"");
    header("Accept-Range: bytes");
    set_time_limit(0);
    readfile("{$downloadFile}");
    header("Connection: close");

/**
* Else we're building a new signature image
*/
}else{
    $data=$_POST['data'];
    $data=str_replace(' ','+',$data);   // convert any whitespace
    /**
    * Now let's decode it so it's recognized as an img
    */
    $decodeData=@base64_decode($data);
    /**
    * Finally, save her
    */
    $file="{$dd_savePath}/".($action=="sig" ? "{$prependSig}{$fileName}" : "{$prependTxt}{$fileName}");
    if(@file_put_contents($file, $decodeData)) {
        @chmod($file,0777);
        /**
        * If we've saved a signature, let's replicate it to proper size
        * since our signature object is bigger (in real dimensions) than what we want
        * See our css+html notes
        */
        switch($action) {
            case "sig":
                $newFile=$dd_savePath.'/tmp_'.$fileName;
                $newSig=new createSignature($file,$newFile);
                $result=$newSig->makePNG($width,$height);
                if($result==true) {
                    // Finally, we want to delete the original and replace it with the new resized one
                    @unlink($file);
                    $finalName=str_replace('tmp_',$prependSig,$newFile);
                    @rename($newFile,$finalName);
                    //
                    $finalName=substr(strrchr($finalName,'/'),1);
                    echo "success|{$finalName}";
                }else{
                    echo "failed";
                }
                break;
            default:
                echo "success";
        }

    }else{
        echo "{$file}";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your js code would be more useful than your php in this case

Comment: For the mouse position read this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/mouse-position/ . As for the second issue, I can't replicate it. I add a background, draw on the canvas, save and the image contains both background and drawing. The third issue is a bit more complex, if you want to only delete the drawing and not the background I think they need to be on two separate canvases

Comment: @JonasGrumann thank you, I will read the article, hopefully find what I need to change in the js. Yes the issue with the background and lines is a mystery for me...but with two canvases how can I be save both in one image?

Comment: When you click on save you copy the background canvas and the drawing canvas onto a new one and export that.

Comment: Hi, @JonasGrumann I  made some test with the width and height of the canvas and if the canvas is 320 width and 240 height the background with the lines I draw is saved... There is a form that I could save a bigger canvas?? I need a canvas like 600 width 600 height

Comment: canvas.toDataURL(); should include the whole canvas, just make the canvas bigger and it should work

Comment: I think that my js is very bad... now in console show me in data "largedata" and give me error... the background image is lightweight so maybe I should see a better js for my type of canvas

Comment: Could you post your current js? Or even better set up a fiddle on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @JonasGrumann here is the js in fiddle : jsfiddle.net/ak2etLro